# Como fazer um teste unitário utilizando Flask e Django

Tags: python, django, flask

Sou novo na área de testes com python utilizando django e flask. Utilizando a biblioteca pytest, como seria implementação de testes dos seguintes métodos e o que poderia ser testado? Se alguém pudesse me dar uma luz iria ajudar bastante!

```
import os

from flask import Flask, session, flash, redirect, render_template, request
from src.dao import UserDao

app = Flask(__name__)
secret = os.environ.get('SESSIONKEY')
app.secret_key = secret
user = UserDao()


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session['usuario_logado'] = None
    session.modified = True
    return redirect('/')

@app.route('/autenticar', methods=['POST'])
def autenticar():
    if (user.read(request.form['email'], request.form['senha'])):
        session['usuario_logado'] = user.nome
        session.modified = True
        return redirect('/perfil')
    else:
        flash("Email ou senha incorretos")
        return redirect('/login')

@app.route('/criar', methods=['POST'])
def criar():
    if (user.create(request.form['email'], request.form['nome'], request.form['senha'], request.form['valida_senha'])):
        session['usuario_logado'] = request.form['nome']
        return redirect('/perfil')
    else:
        flash(user.message)
        return redirect('/register')
```

**O que tentei fazer**

```
def test_logout_page():
    with app.test_client() as test_client:
        response = test_client.get('/logout')
        assert response.status_code == 200
        
        
def test_autenticar_page():
    with app.test_client() as test_client:
        response = test_client.get('/login')
        assert response.status_code == 200
        

def test_criar_page():
    with app.test_client() as test_client:
        response = test_client.get('/register')
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

**Resultados**

No teste test_logout_page() ele falha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nos demais testes passam, mas achei muito simples. Como seria uma forma de criar um teste mais robusto, tipo criar um usuário e validar uma requisição, encerrar uma sessão na página e etc?

Comment: Não entendo como os outros testes estão passando. No teste vc faz um `request.get` e na view vc especifica o método `POST`. Tem certeza que o código que você postou é o que está sendo testado? Outra coisa
: acredito que `app.test_client` seja uma _fixture_, correto? Poste ela aqui também.

Comment: Eu só utilizo o arquivo app.py onde contém os endpoints e o arquivo de teste test_app.py que contém os testes dos endpoints, esse **app.test_client** eu peguei de um exemplo.

Comment: Faça um troubleshooting do seu teste, deixando apenas o `test_autenticar_page` depois comente aqui o resultado.

Comment: O teste acabou passando:

============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-6.0.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /home/rseiji/workspace-faculdade/tech.academy/venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/rseiji/workspace-estudo/tech.academy/tests/unit
plugins: cov-2.10.1
collecting ... collected 1 item
test_app.py::test_autenticar_page PASSED                                 [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 1.33s ===============================

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Sem ver a fixture fica difícil. Já tentou configurar o método POST como nas outras views?